# Inconsistent careers ad behavior

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs, advertising

When viewing question page as anonymous visitor or low rep user, we are presented with advertisements on top of the page. All is good.

90% of those ads belong to Careers, which is also good.

90% of the Careers ads are served via adzerk, e.g. this one: ([full link](http://engine.adzerk.net/r?e=eyJhdiI6NDE0LCJhdCI6NCwiY20iOjI5MTEsImNoIjoxMTc4LCJjciI6NTkxOCwiZGkiOiIxN2E5MDNkNWVhNzQ0NWQzOWMxYzBhMTAwNTM0YThmZiIsImRtIjoxLCJmYyI6MTAxOTYsImZsIjo3NDczLCJrdyI6InNzaCx4LXVzZXItcmVnaXN0ZXJlZCIsIm53IjoyMiwicGMiOjAsInByIjoxNjA0LCJydCI6MSwicmYiOiJodHRwOi8vc2VydmVyZmF1bHQuY29tL3Bvc3RzLzU4Mzg5OS9lZGl0Iiwic3QiOjgyNzgsInpuIjo0OSwidHMiOjEzOTU1ODAyMTc2NzMsInVyIjoiaHR0cDovL2NhcmVlcnMuc3RhY2tvdmVyZmxvdy5jb20vIn0&s=Es_-KuSO4zLWL6IqB_GGjIBA1zk))

> [image]

However, 1 out of 10 times I get such and ad, which is just a plain image which directly links to http://careers.stackoverflow.com/:

> [image]

I don't have anything against the ad itself which is nice however, I see possible issues with this:

1. The normal ads open the target site in a new tab, the direct non adzerk ad in the same tab. It can be unpleasant surprise.
2. In the normal ads, I can click "like" or "dislike" and it affects how often I'll see them in rotation. The direct ad, being plain image, doesn't have those icons.
3. I assume adzerk is used for a reason, e.g. tracking popularity of ads, so Stack Exchange is not getting this information for those direct ads.

Is there a reason behind this? Or just some oversight?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fix has been checked in for opening those ads in a new window. It will go live some point today soon (we deploy to production several times a day usually).

I'm going to go ahead and mark this as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that will do! :)

Answer (score 5):

We do serve some ads ourselves (mostly remnant ads, or in some cases company page ads) which you pointed out.  We should have consistency on point #1, and we'll get that fixed.

Only Adzerk ads will have the upvote downvote functionality for now.  It's not an oversight, just a limitation of adserving on our side for the time being.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for clarifying everything!